# PyMySQL is stuck on fetch_one() with no errors

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

Hello so here's a part of my code:

```
db = pymysql.connect(
    host = ....., 
    user = ....., 
    passwd = ....., 
    db = ....., 
    port = ....., 
    connect_timeout = 5 , 
    use_unicode = True, 
    charset = "utf8",
    autocommit = True,
)

c = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.SSDictCursor)
data  = c.execute(my_query) # for example SELECT * FROM PEOPLE
run = True
while run:
    ### processing in batches of 50
    batch = []
    for i in range(50):
        row = data.fetchone()
        if not row:
             run = False 
             break 
        row = do_something(row)
        batch += [row]

    do_stuff_that takes_3_minutes(batch)
```

my problem is that after an hour or so, this code gets stuck on `data.fetchone()`, but it doesn't exit or show any errors, just gets stuck on it. i knew that because, i added print statement before and after every instruction and the last output to the console was the print before `fetchone()`

Comment: Can you query the database from another source during the time that your program is stuck?

Comment: @SamHollenbach yes, if i launch another script when it's stuck, the other script works normally

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if just closing and re-instantiating the cursor here would be a good enough workaround.

Comment: @SamHollenbach, the problem is that are no errors, no exceptions ... NOTHING , so i can't really know when to close the cursor and reopen it, what i'm doing is creating threads (custom threads that i made without timeout property) every time i want to fetch_one, and when a thread times out, i recreate the database connection and recreate the cursor

Comment: Yeah thats peculiar.Maybe check out  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305998/python-script-stops-no-errors-giving and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113566/arcpy-script-stops-running-randomly-with-no-error-returned. The second one specifically mentions this possibly happening when your program runs out of RAM. This could be the case, since you are querying data over the course of a long time. You could have a memory leak somewhere that is causing your script to stop after a long time.

Comment: @SamHollenbach the problem isn't a ram issue, since using a new thread with a timeout everytime i want to do fetchone() bypassed the issue (now everytime a fetchone thread timesout, i'm renewing the connection)